# Postman to post a datetime value to database

Tags: c#, postman

I have a database with a `DateTime` column and a post method in web api. I'd like to test it if the data sent can be inserted into the database. But I don't know the correct data format to send from postman.
[image: this is to post]

[image: This is pre-request script]

Comment: The correct dat**e** format is determined by the API, not by Postman, and a commonly used format is [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

Comment: How can I post a `DateTime` object into `{{dateString}}`?

Comment: To test that is works, just try `"joineddate": "2022-09-04T11:20:00.0Z"`  if that doesn't work, then it doesn't matter how you configure postman, it isn't going to work until youfind out what the CORRECT format is.

Answer (score 1):

To use variables in the raw json body, you need to put quotes around it:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "joineddate": "{{dateString}}"
}
```

and postman will replace the string inside the quotes. Otherwise you will have invalid json. And as the commenters have said, make sure you are using the correct format.